# Программное создание VPN подключения на Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, vpn

Есть VPN сервер и я к нему подключаюсь
по протоколу PPTP или L2TP
с помощью стандартных средств виндовс,
аля http://skynet.com.ua/help/nastroika-vpn-soedineniya-dlya-windows-7.
Знаю что все это нужно проводить только раз,
но скажем так, я часто меняю виндовс.

Так вот, мне это не нравится и я решил написать
программу, которая будет делать эти действия вместо меня.

Погуглив как это сделать я не нашел ничего кроме
варианта создания шаблона файла "Rasphone.pbk" 
и дальнейшей его перезаписи и использования команды rasdial
для соединения и разъединению. Конечно можно написать bat-файл, 
но мне это не подходит. Мне нужен более гибкий метод.

Я думаю, что есть windows api для этого, но не могу найти информации об этом.

Может кто знает как это сделать?

Comment: А можно не парить мозг и купить роутер, где этот vpn будет подниматься сам. На windows будет приходить обычная локалка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант, который я реализовал - работал с `rasdial` через `QProcess`. Работать с ним очень просто, можно даже нашлепать форму и прикрепить `QSettings`, чтобы все было по фен-шую.

Может есть какое-то решение с помощью `WinAPI`, но способ выше - проще.

Мой старый проект(но я там работал с `rasdial` именно для подключения к интернету): [Github](https://github.com/aplinxy9plin/IHelper)

Comment: Могли бы вы привести какие-то примеры кода или ссылки на подробную информацию такой реализации?

Comment: добавил в ответ

Comment: @МиронСосяк, если вам помог мой ответ, то отметьте его галочкой, как решение проблемы.